# Flutter: OTP is being sent again and again although user is registered in Firebase Auth

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I'm using `flutter_auth` package to apply **Phone Auth**. Normally it sends the **OTP** when a new phone number is registered. But it is sending **OTP again and again** although the user's phone number is there in `Firebase authentication list`

One more thing is it is working fine on few devices, the normal way. Is there any thing wrong with syncing issue? means does it take some time to get sync with firestore or not?

Here's my code of `phone auth` What am I doing wrong?

```
phoneAuth(String phone) async {
      FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

      _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: phone,
          timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
          verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential credential) async {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            AuthResult authResult =
                await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

            FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

            if (user != null) {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => AddContacts(
                            user: user,
                          )));
            } else {
              print("ERROR");
            }
          },
          verificationFailed: (AuthException exception) {
            Toast.show('Try Again Later', context,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                duration: 3,
                gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
          },
          codeSent: (String verification, [int forceResendingToken]) {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                barrierDismissible: false,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                    title: Text('Enter 6-Digit Code'),
                    content: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          controller: _controllerCode,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          maxLength: 6,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            errorText: validateCode(_controllerCode.text),
                            hintText: 'Enter Code',
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
                            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                            focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Wait for Automatic Detection!",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * .05),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                        child: Text("Confirm"),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        onPressed: () async {
                          setState(() {
                            _controllerCode.text.isEmpty
                                ? _validateCode = true
                                : _validateCode = false;
                          });
                          final code = _controllerCode.text.trim();
                          AuthCredential credential =
                              PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                                  verificationId: verification, smsCode: code);
                          AuthResult result =
                              await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
                          FirebaseUser user = result.user;
                          if (user != null) {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                new MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => AddContacts(
                                          user: user,
                                        )));
                          } else {
                            Toast.show("ERROR: Code mismatch!", context,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                gravity: Toast.TOP);
                          }
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                });
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: null);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discussed the problem on LinkedIn chat privately. We reach to the point of your problem which is - as you said..

> OTP should be sent only when the user is log in first time not after that. if I enter my number on another device its send the OTP again

So you was having an issue to understand how the Auth OTP works.

> OTP code is sent every time you request it even if you are already registered or logged in on another device.

And you asked then..

> Means it will sent the OTP everytime not matter the user is logged in already or new?

The answer is YES, it will. So your codes working fine for now. It's all about the concepts of how it's working.

Comment: Your reply helped in getting a better understanding of how this authentication works.

Comment: But the question that I now have is:
What should I do if I want to register users with verification of their mobile numbers using OTP, but keeping them logged in if the app is continued to be used on the same device. Basically I don't want to have to send an SMS for every time an existing users wishes to login. Any online tutorials you could point me to? (I am completely new to flutter and firebase). Thanks.

Comment: This implementation is already exist when you sign in with credential of Phone. So every time he close application and open it again, it will have the FirebaseUser not equals to null, so you already have this information and do it whatever you want.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clarifying that. Could you guide me to an online tutorial that explains flutter+firebase authentication from start to end (that does this check for already registered and logged in users)?

Comment: First, I must advice you to see the official documents for Firebase with Android, it seems to be much close, Second, please read the README of flutter packages for Firebase and test their examples for each one, Third, you can attend these courses on udemy, https://www.udemy.com/course/flutter-firebase-build-a-complete-app-for-ios-android/ https://www.udemy.com/course/build-a-social-network-with-flutter-and-firebase/ , I know it's not FREE, but you can search for more tutorials on YouTube.

Comment: Thanks. I will try those.